# Scope of HttpContext.Current.Items

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Are the `HttpContext.Current.Items` lost when a `Server.Transfer();` occurs?

If so what is the best way for me to send information to another page
without going through the Session?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to go through the session?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, the context would still be valid. It would become invalid or break if you use Response.Redirect().

See article [The HttpContext Items Collection](http://odetocode.com/articles/111.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can access Page.PreviousPage property with all data on it when using Server.Transfer().
And also yes, context would be valid.

Comment: would the context still be valid or would a new context have been built for the call ?

Comment: There is a caveat that applies to referencing controls and their value from Page.PreviousPage via FindControl if the previous page is using a master page.  You have to first referenece the content placeholder  is that you have to first reference the content placeholder (null checks omitted for brevity):  

`var cp = this.PreviousPage.Controls[0].FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");`  

`TextBox txtFirstName = (TextBox)cp.FindControl("txtFirstName");`